# URL redirecting to old server path

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, web

We are moving our applications from windows 2003 server to windows 2008 R2 server. The application in question have a default.htm page for redirecting to application start page. Also we changed the application structure while moving it on to new server. Due to this structure change, we had to change the redirection URL in default.htm page.

During this move I got a weird issue. When we changed the DNS to point to IP address of new server and tried accessing site, DNS was being resolved with correct IP but redirect happening was old one.This issue was happening only on IE on internal machines. Every other browser was redirecting to correct path. If we were accessing this site from external machines, even IE was redirecting properly. I checked all the configurations and settings and every thing was correct. I confirmed that this is not an application issue. Can somebody point me to the possible cause for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are seeing a browser cache issue. Clear the cache on an affected PC and test again. I bet you won't see an issue.

Comment: I cleared the cache but it did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Finally my issue is fixed. Clearing browser cache using "Safety > Delete Browser History" didn't work but clearing browser cache through developer options worked "F12 > Cache > Clear Browser Cache".

Comment: Right. History != cache. Glad you got it fixed.